# How to include ws2tcpip.h and ws2def.h into a Visual C++ 2008 project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, network-programming, winsock, winsock2

I am new to Visual C++. I have installed Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition (with SP1) in Windows XP. I am trying to compile an open source Visual C++ project.

I have open the `.vcproj` project in VC++ 2008 Express. When I use Build > Rebuild Solution, it shows the following output:

```
3 error(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The following are the 3 errors:

```
error C3861: 'IN6_IS_ADDR_MULTICAST': identifier not found

error C2065: 'IPPROTO_IPV6' : undeclared identifier

error C2065: 'IPPROTO_IPV6' : undeclared identifier
```

I have been googling for a very long time. I found that these identifier are available in the following files:

- `ws2tcpip.h`
- `ws2def.h`
- `winsock2.h`

If I am not mistaken, these files are used by Windows developers to do network/socket programming. It should be available somewhere in Windows.

May I know what is the difference between `error C2065: undeclared identifier` and `error C3861: identifier not found`?

How can I include `ws2tcpip.h` and `ws2def.h` into a Visual C++ 2008 project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it as simple as #including these headers in the appropriate files?

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
```

Note that winsock2.h must be #included *before* ws2tcpip.h, otherwise you'll get compile errors like "ip_mreq::imr_multiaddr uses undefined struc in_addr" and "Byte is not a member of in6_addr::__unnamed".

Answer (score 1):

> [The WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN macro prevents the Winsock.h from being included by the Windows.h header.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
```

Or add project - derective WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN